# BIRT maven configuration not working

Tags: maven, maven-2, birt

BIRT maven configuration not working as expected.

Added following dependencies in the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi.services</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.icu</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi.services</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.v20140312-2051</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.icu</artifactId>
    <version>52.1.1.v201501240615</version>
</dependency>
```

the jar has been downloaded and Maven update was done on the project. Still, java code gives compile time error?

```
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.*;
```

Compile time error: `The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved`

How can we resolve these dependencies and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are just importing the runtime library, not the engine api. Therefore, your compiler complains about missing classes.

You need the following library to import: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt/report-engine/3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to use by doing some changes in dependencies

Add these two jars in lib folder.

> "flute-1.3.jar" &
>   "org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb-2.10.1.v20130422-1135.jar"

Dependency Update:

```
//Start of birt
    compile(group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', name: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', version: '4.4.2') {
        exclude(group: 'org.milyn', module: 'flute')
        exclude(group: 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime', module: 'org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb')
    }
    //End of birt
```